# Diagonalizing Hamiltonian for a ring of particles

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, fourier-transform, second-quantization

I have a ring with $N$ interacting particles (bosons) separated by length $a$ with the hamiltonian

$$H = -t \sum_{\alpha=0}^N (b_{\alpha+1}^\dagger b_\alpha + h.c.) + u \sum_{\alpha=0}^N  b_\alpha^\dagger  b_\alpha (b_\alpha^\dagger  b_\alpha -1)$$

where $b$ are boson annihilation operators and $\alpha$ is the index denoting the position on the ring. The noninteracting part of the hamiltonian is not diagonal. I am given a hint to do a Fourier transform

$$b_\alpha = \sum_{i=-\infty}^{\infty} e^{i k_i a \alpha} a_i$$

with $a_i$ being the bosonic operators in momentum space. After I transform the noninteracting part of $H$ using this, I get the following expression:

$$\sum_{\alpha=1}^N \sum_{i,j=-\infty}^\infty a_i^\dagger a_j e^{ia\alpha (k_j - k_i)} (e^{ik_j a}+e^{-ik_i a})$$

I suspect this simplifies somehow via the Kronecker delta but I can't see it. How do I simplify this expression?

Answer (score 1):

You need to split the exponentials and use the property 
that, if $\omega_n=e^{2\pi i/n}$, 
then the sum of $n$'th roots of unity
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n \omega_n^k = 0\, .
$$

---

Added in view of comments.

Actually the $(N+1)\times (N+1)$ Fourier matrix ${\cal F}$ is given by
$
{\cal F}_{km}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{N+1}}\omega_{N+1}^{km}
$
and is entirely expressed in terms powers of the fundamental root of unity $\omega_{N+1}$ s.t.
$\omega_{N+1}^{N+1}=1$.

I suspect that the bounds on your sum should really run from $i=0$ to $i=N$.

Here's an intuitive way to see what's going on.  Consider the matrix 
$$
P=\left(\begin{array}{ccccc}
0&1&0&\ldots&0 \\
0&0&1&\ldots&0 \\
\vdots & &\vdots && \vdots \\
0&0&\ldots &0&1 \\
1& 0&\ldots & 0&0
\end{array}\right)
$$
which transforms the boson operator at position $a$ to the boson operator at $a-1$.  By construction this matrix $P$ will commute with your Hamiltonian since it is cyclic in the positions of the bosons.  Thus, $H$ and $P$ have common eigenvectors.

The eigenvalues of $P$ are easy to find: since $P^{N+1}=I$ (the unit matrix), it follows that the eigenvalues of the $(N+1)$th roots of unity, and the eigenvectors are just the columns of the Fourier matrix.

In your sum, you want to write $e^{i a\alpha k_j}\times
e^{-ia \alpha k_i}(e^{ik_ja}+e^{-ik_ja})$ as something l ike 
$e^{ia \alpha k_j}+e^{i \alpha k_i}$ 
(i.e. split the exponentials) and use the summation of roots of unity to first carry the sum over $i$ or $j$.

Nota: I suspect there might be a small error in your expression as you typeset it. Either way, this should be enough for you to complete the calculation.  In case of doubt, try constructing $P$ for $N+1=3$ or $5$ to get a sense of what goes where.

Comment: How do I know they're roots of unity though? And how do you mean split the exponentials?

Comment: expanded on my answer...